# How to set bold label when radio-button is checked

Tags: html, css

Why is the label not bold with this setting?

```
      <form class="input-group">
<div class="btn-section-operation" id="btn-container-table">
    <label for="radio-selection-range-rows" class="radio-custom-label"><input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rows" name="radio-selection" type="radio" checked="checked">Rows</label>
    <label for="radio-selection-range-rel" class="radio-custom-label"><input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rel" name="radio-selection" type="radio">Rows with relations</label>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMELrp?editors=1100)

Comment: You need to add `jQuery` code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `label:checked`, but `input:checked` for a checked checkbox. Furthermore you use the sibling selector, but the element you want to style is the parent (label is the parent of input). There is no parent selector in CSS, so my solution would be to use a `span` around the text.

```
<label for="radio-selection-range-rows" class="radio-custom-label">
    <input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rows" name="radio-selection" type="radio" checked="checked">
    <span>Rows</span>
</label>
```

And then select like this:

```
input:checked ~ span {
    border-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You could also place the input `outside` the `label` and use other css, but you probably have reasons to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check updated snippet below...

```css
label input:checked + span {
  border-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-section-operation {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<form class="input-group">
  <div class="btn-section-operation" id="btn-container-table">
    <label for="radio-selection-range-rows" class="radio-custom-label"><input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rows" name="radio-selection" type="radio" checked="checked"><span>Rows</span></label>

    <label for="radio-selection-range-rel" class="radio-custom-label"><input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rel" name="radio-selection" type="radio"><span>Rows with relations</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since the `border-width` is never defined, `border-color` will do nothing.